# Annual moving window over a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics, time-series, mean

I have a data frame of discharge data. Below is a reproducible example:

```
library(lubridate)
Date <- sample(seq(as.Date('1981/01/01'), as.Date('1982/12/31'), by="day"), 24)
Date <- sort(Date, decreasing = F)
Station <- rep(as.character("A"), 24)
Discharge <- rnorm(n = 24, mean = 1, 1)
df <- cbind.data.frame(Station, Date, Discharge)
df$Year <- year(df$Date)
df$Month <- month(df$Date)
df$Day <- day(df$Date)
```

The output:

```
> df
   Station       Date   Discharge Year Month Day
1        A 1981-01-23  0.75514968 1981     1  23
2        A 1981-02-17 -0.08552776 1981     2  17
3        A 1981-03-20  1.47586712 1981     3  20
4        A 1981-04-26  3.64823544 1981     4  26
5        A 1981-05-22  1.21880453 1981     5  22
6        A 1981-05-23  2.19482857 1981     5  23
7        A 1981-07-02 -0.13598754 1981     7   2
8        A 1981-07-23  0.12365626 1981     7  23
9        A 1981-07-24  2.12557882 1981     7  24
10       A 1981-09-02  2.79879494 1981     9   2
11       A 1981-09-04  1.67926948 1981     9   4
12       A 1981-11-06  0.49720784 1981    11   6
13       A 1981-12-21 -0.25272271 1981    12  21
14       A 1982-04-08  1.39706157 1982     4   8
15       A 1982-04-19 -0.13965981 1982     4  19
16       A 1982-05-26  0.55238425 1982     5  26
17       A 1982-06-23  3.94639154 1982     6  23
18       A 1982-06-25 -0.03415929 1982     6  25
19       A 1982-07-15  1.00996167 1982     7  15
20       A 1982-09-11  3.18225186 1982     9  11
21       A 1982-10-17  0.30875497 1982    10  17
22       A 1982-10-30  2.26209011 1982    10  30
23       A 1982-11-06  0.34430489 1982    11   6
24       A 1982-11-19  2.28251458 1982    11  19
```

What I need to do is to create a moving window function using base R. I have tried using `runner` package but it is proving not to be so flexible. This moving window (say 3) shall take 3 rows at a time and calculate the `mean` discharge. This window shall continue till the last date of the year 1981. Another window shall start from 1982 and do the same. How to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using base R only

```
w=3

df$DischargeM=sapply(1:nrow(df),function(x){
  tmp=NA
  if (x>=w) {
    if (length(unique(df$Year[(x-w+1):x]))==1) {
      tmp=mean(df$Discharge[(x-w+1):x])
    }
  }
  tmp
})

   Station       Date  Discharge Year Month Day DischargeM
1        A 1981-01-21  2.0009355 1981     1  21         NA
2        A 1981-02-11  0.5948567 1981     2  11         NA
3        A 1981-04-17  0.2637090 1981     4  17 0.95316705
4        A 1981-04-18  3.9180253 1981     4  18 1.59219699
5        A 1981-05-09 -0.2589129 1981     5   9 1.30760712
6        A 1981-07-05  1.1055913 1981     7   5 1.58823456
7        A 1981-07-11  0.7561600 1981     7  11 0.53427946
8        A 1981-07-22  0.0978999 1981     7  22 0.65321706
9        A 1981-08-04  0.5410163 1981     8   4 0.46502541
10       A 1981-08-13 -0.5044425 1981     8  13 0.04482458
11       A 1981-10-06  1.5954315 1981    10   6 0.54400178
12       A 1981-11-08 -0.5757041 1981    11   8 0.17176164
13       A 1981-12-24  1.3892440 1981    12  24 0.80299047
14       A 1982-01-07  1.9363874 1982     1   7         NA
15       A 1982-02-20  1.4340554 1982     2  20         NA
16       A 1982-05-29  0.4536461 1982     5  29 1.27469632
17       A 1982-06-10  2.9776761 1982     6  10 1.62179253
18       A 1982-06-17  1.6371733 1982     6  17 1.68949847
19       A 1982-06-28  1.7585579 1982     6  28 2.12446908
20       A 1982-08-17  0.8297518 1982     8  17 1.40849432
21       A 1982-09-21  1.6853808 1982     9  21 1.42456348
22       A 1982-11-13  0.6066167 1982    11  13 1.04058309
23       A 1982-11-16  1.4989263 1982    11  16 1.26364126
24       A 1982-11-28  0.2273658 1982    11  28 0.77763625
```

(make sure your df is ordered).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using dplyr and the `rollmean` or `rollmeanr` function from zoo.

You group the data by year, and apply the `rollmeanr` in a mutate function.

library(dplyr)

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Year) %>% 
  mutate(avg = zoo::rollmeanr(Discharge, k = 3, fill = NA))

# A tibble: 24 x 7
# Groups:   Year [2]
   Station Date       Discharge  Year Month   Day    avg
   <chr>   <date>         <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>  <dbl>
 1 A       1981-01-04    1.00    1981     1     4 NA    
 2 A       1981-03-26    0.0468  1981     3    26 NA    
 3 A       1981-03-28    0.431   1981     3    28  0.494
 4 A       1981-05-04    1.30    1981     5     4  0.593
 5 A       1981-08-26    2.06    1981     8    26  1.26 
 6 A       1981-10-14    1.09    1981    10    14  1.48 
 7 A       1981-12-10    1.28    1981    12    10  1.48 
 8 A       1981-12-23    0.668   1981    12    23  1.01 
 9 A       1982-01-02   -0.333   1982     1     2 NA    
10 A       1982-04-13    0.800   1982     4    13 NA    
# ... with 14 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly let me know if this is what you were anticipating

Base version:

```
result <- transform(df, 
      Discharge_mean = ave(Discharge,Year,
                           FUN= function(x) rollapply(x,width = 3, mean, align='right',fill=NA))
      )
```

dplyr version:

```
result <-df %>%
  group_by(Year)%>%
  mutate(Discharge_mean=rollapply(Discharge,3,mean,align='right',fill=NA))
```

Output:

```
> result
  Station       Date    Discharge Year Month Day Discharge_mean
1        A 1981-01-09  0.560448487 1981     1   9             NA
2        A 1981-01-17  0.006777809 1981     1  17             NA
3        A 1981-02-08  2.008959399 1981     2   8      0.8587286
4        A 1981-02-21  1.166452993 1981     2  21      1.0607301
5        A 1981-04-12  3.120080595 1981     4  12      2.0984977
6        A 1981-04-24  2.647325960 1981     4  24      2.3112865
7        A 1981-05-01  0.764980310 1981     5   1      2.1774623
8        A 1981-05-20  2.203700845 1981     5  20      1.8720024
9        A 1981-06-19  0.519390897 1981     6  19      1.1626907
10       A 1981-07-06  1.704146872 1981     7   6      1.4757462
# 14 more rows
```